# can i run two copies of the same war in different context paths on tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

I have my war running on tomcat in a context path - say /path1.

I've made some more changes to my codebase, added more classes, jars etc, and now without disturbing the first war that is running on /path1, i want to add this war to /path2.

Can this be done?

Because when I tried this the second war is failing to start when spring loads -

```
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 7, 2011 4:46:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/path2] startup failed due to previous errors
```

And there is no stack trace or anything though i've set log level to debug.

I think there is no problem with the code because when I run this on my local machine and on a server where the first one is not running it works fine.  When i try to run this on the server with /path1 active then it fails.

Thanks!

Comment: You should find some additional log messages in one of the logs in Tomcat's logs directory

Comment: does this mean anything? INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/path2/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class.  this appears just before the listenerStart error.

Comment: Please pay attention to comment from Adam. Tomcat's startup errors are logged into Tomcat's own logfile, not the webapp's own logfile. Peek around in `/logs` folder of Tomcat. As to the INFO message, this is already a smell: you should not have any copy of a servletcontainer-specific library anywhere else in the classpath outside where it belongs/originates (the `/lib` folder of the servletcontainer itself), thus also **not** in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Get rid of all servletcontainer-specific libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'listenerStart' bit suggests that the error is in a ServletContextListener, so if you have any of those in your code, take a hard look, and see what they're doing; are they accessing any resources that the other instance might then try to share?

Comment: thanks for all your answers!  Couldn't spend more time on this.  Had to move on.  So i brought down the other instance and ran the new war and it ran well.  So maybe it had something to do with shared resources!